# Looking for a Horowitz game

Tags: tactics, master-games, famous-games, download-games

I just remembered a puzzle from a Horowitz game in which he played white against an Italian (I believe) player whose name started with "M".

The black queen was defending f6, preventing Bxf6#. There was also a pawn about to promote on d7, and a rook stopping it on d8.

How can I find the game in which the position occurred? I can't recall Black player's name.

Comment: There are 293 Horowitz games listed at http://www.chessgames.com/player/israel_albert_horowitz.html
You might scan that list to see if any of the opponents' names rings a bell.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be [Horowitz vs. NN](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1056889) (1939).  (I realize "NN" doesn't start with an M, and may or may not be Italian, and the pawn isn't on d7... but memory can be a funny thing.)

This might be the position you're remembering:

```
rnb1qrk1/pppp1ppp/5B2/b2BP2Q/8/2P5/P4PPP/RN3RK1 b - - 2 13
```

I found this by putting in Horowitz playing as White in chessgames.com, then just sort of went through games in a pseudo-random order (start with "M", hit anything remotely Italian, guess at others) until I found a likely candidate.

Answer (score 1):

If the game exists in a database, you can search for all games where Horowitz plays white.  This search resulted in 151 games on chessgames.com.  To further narrow the field, you can have it search by positions with a white pawn on d7 and a black rook on d8.  This isn't a feature on any online database that I know of, but many databases do allow this. My database shows over 2100 games with these pieces, and is limited to games played after 1988.  Neither of these searches provided me with this game, although I restricted it further by saying that white won.  Maybe I should have checked players whose first name begins with 'M.'

Comment: Horowitz died in 1973, so it certainly won't be in your database.

Comment: @HerbWolfe I know that.  That's actually why I included this fact.  This was meant to show that this two piece pattern is well known and popular.  Although I assume that this is ~ a decade span instead of the ~30 years.